# Deselect cell after time when i selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nstimer

I wanna deselect my tableview cell. But automaticly after 5 sec it selected. I try `NSTimer` like this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector ([tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

in this method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but XCode says me failed.

Please help 
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably has to be performed on the main thread. Change it to a dispatch and it will sort itself out.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
});
```

This will dispatch the call after 5 seconds and then perform the deselection on the main thread.

Comment: The dispatch_async is unnecessary here as dispatch_after will be executed on the queue provided(main queue).

Comment: You should make a weak pointer to tableView so you do not leak memory in case you navigate away from the scene where tableView is located and it needs to be deallocated.